# Decompose homography matrix to rotation and translation

Tags: rotation, computer-vision, homography, 3d-reconstruction, decomposition

how can you get the correct R and t from H when you have 4 solutions.
From my understanding you can only eliminate two.

Is there really no way to get the correct solutions if you only have points on a single plane?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is one approach to best select solution from two possible solutions. When you decompose Homography,after eliminating 2 possible solutions from 4,you get two set of

[image]
rotations, translations and normals.

Normals are nothing but possible `camera_normals` wrt scene of first image(when you estimate Homography between two images). So having known `camera_normal` wrt planar scene when first image was captured, you can choose solution corresponding to closest normal from ***n1,n2*** by computing dot product `dot(camera_normal,n1)` and `dot(camera_normal,n2)`, whichever is larger.

Thanks

---

Edit: `camera_normal` explanation

Planar Homography assumes that features used for computing Homography between tow images are in a plane. So `camera_normal` is direction of `z-axis` of camera in plane's frame.

Comment: What do you mean by the camera's normal. The normal vec from the plane from the first image. But then I would already know if n1 or n2 is correct. But how should I know that if I don't know the scene. Or is the camera normal something else?

Comment: @user3077796 camera_normal is unit vector of camera's z axis in plane's frame(Here plane can be taken as plane containing features )